# Convert HTML to HTML 5?

Tags: html5

I have a website which is in XHTML (wordpress coded). I need to convert it into HTML 5. I just started learning about HTML 5 tags like section, nav, footer etc. While finding deep into it, I came across a site which actually converts the XHTML code into HTML 5.

Now I am confused, any how I have to learn HTML 5, but for the time sake is it a good decision to use that site? The converted HTML 5 code contains all the new tags, but is that actual pure method to do that? Will this converted code will be approved by W3C as HTML 5?

Here is the site:

http://mynthon.net/tools/xhtml-to-html5/

Comment: @hazelnut is very right you know... Once you are into the converter crap, you will never make yourself up for the learning phase and will always go for the converter calling it as 'for time sake'. Don't do it like that... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use any converters. That make your Code Buggy. You should use your own knowledge and convert it manually! Learn HTML5 and it is very useful four you and the future. :-)